# use values(features) in a vector to calculate cosine similarity for opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv, vector, cosine-similarity

I am recently working on a project where in I have extracted some features regarding an image, and want to find if there are any similarities between two images using those features. 
Here are the list of features that I have extracted:

1. Aspect ratio (width/height)
2. Normalised area (Cropped roi's area to input image area)
3. Centre of the cropped image
   and other features from a single image

Now, I want to feed these values into a vector, and use that vector to find cosine similarity. In Short, use such vector from two images, and find the similarity between them. 
I know how cross product of two vectors works, but
I want help in storing these images into  vector and usage of the vector. Any suggestions would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh, not too difficult.

step 1: fill your feature(Mat) with numbers, one after the other:

```
Mat feature; // you could use a std::vector, too, but cv::Mat has the 
             // handy dot-product used below already built in.
feature.push_back(aspect_ratio);
feature.push_back(area);
feature.push_back(center.x);
feature.push_back(center.y);
feature.push_back(more_stuff);
...
```

step 2: to compare those features, use the cosine norm :

```
Mat feature_a, feature_b; // composed like above
double ab = feature_a.dot(feature_b);
double aa = feature_a.dot(feature_a);
double bb = feature_b.dot(feature_b);
return -ab / sqrt(aa*bb);
```

Comment: Thanks berak.. I understand how you are passing values. Can we store any values in matrices? I mean can the values be of float and double datatypes?

Comment: the 1st one you push_back() will determine the type of the Mat. anything after that will get converted to the type of the 1st.

Comment: Hi @berak, I am trying to use the code you helped me with, but I see theta values to be negative. What can I infer from that?

Comment: how would i know, what theta is ? (all of the context missing)

Comment: Sorry, My mistake! I assumed the -ab/sqrt(aa*bb) to be theta value.I now understand that its cos(theta) value. Thanks!

Comment: I have a doubt regarding the cosine similarity. Can the cosine similarity of two vectors be negative? Also, is there any function across opencv or C++ that can calculate the theta out of cos theta value(if the value is negative)?

Comment: Thanks @berak!! Looks like I have forgotten my basic trigonometry here. Obtuse angles give negative values for cos theta. And cosine similarity says, More nearer to zero, more are they similar. So, i got my answer.

Comment: phew, i'm glad you put in better words i ever would have ;)